# Could not install NuGet package with the correct .NET version

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

I created a few packages on my internal NuGet server (hosted by TeamCity). All packages work as expected except one. I getting error:

> Could not install package 'MYPACKAGE'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

[image: Package info]
[image: Project info]

Everything looks good, but it's impossible to install this package. Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, assembly which was distributed by NuGet was strongly signed by a .snk key. That causes problems.. After removing the key, everything works as it should.

Comment: Do you have more information about your package? I have the same problem but mine isn't signed with a key. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38869711/nuget-package-not-compatible-with-framework