# Nuget package not compatible with framework

Tags: package, nuget, .net-framework-version

I created my own nuget package with the following content:

[image]

I had a default nuspec for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>Communited.PluginService.Base</id>
    <version>5.4.3.4</version>
    <authors>Communited</authors>
    <owners>Communited</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>The Communited PluginService Base application. Needed to run custom plugins</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2016</copyright>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

When installing this in my project I get the following error:

```
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Communited.PluginService.Base 5.4.3.4'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For 
more information, contact the package author.
```

The project that i'm installing it on, is .NET Framework 4.5

What am I doing wrong?

Tim

Comment: Im looking for an answer to this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, Go to View -> Other Windows -> Package Manager Console,

run below command,(provided the package is available for the target framework)

```
update-package -reinstall
```

Here's more information,
[update-package](http://blog.nuget.org/20121231/a-quick-tutorial-on-update-package-command.html)